# Visual Studio 2019 XAML queue build to TFS 2015 failing

Tags: visual-studio-2019, tfs-2015

The last developer had been deploying our Intranet MVC project from VS2019 for years, using a method of XAML queue build up to TFS2015.

However after a recent VS update to 16.10.3 (from 16.1.3) - the queue build is now failing (see attached pic).  It can't find all the config files (even though I can see them in the solution explorer).

I'm yet to determine if it was the VS update that killed it, or some other MS monthly patching (possibly on the TFS server itself).

As I'm very inexperienced in .NET MVC coding (in fact in VS), can anyone spot an obvious reason this is failing?

Traditionally the VS queue build function would complete in <1min, then the zipped up package could be located on the TFS\drops folder, and imported into IIS on the web server.

I'm in the process of restoring the VM to a point prior to the VS update (~65 days ago), and to a time when the Intranet solution was last published successfully.

[image: VS queue build fail]

Comment: It's unlikely that this has anything to do with the Visual Studio version. It's more likely that the developer committed a change that broke something. It's impossible to tell from what you're describing and your screenshot, and there's not really any detail you can provide that will get you a better answer. This is a case where people who are knowledgeable about your software and your environment will need to work together to troubleshoot. Strangers on the internet aren't going to be able to give much guidance.

Comment: I reverted the VM back to the old version of VS, and it did not make any difference.

The build function failed with the same errors as before.

I ended up figuring out the built-in VS publishing function (IIS) and was able to get my zipped file of contents uploaded that way.

I need to migrate the latest copy of the code to Azure Devops and move away from the deprecated TFS 2015.

Research indicates this is not as straight fwd as it sounds.

Comment: Each time I try to clone the DevOps repo down, it replaces all my code with a blank solution (zero code).  Each time I try to point the code to the new DevOps repo, it errors and says the DevOps repo is not empty.

Only way I can think of getting a SINGLE (latest code version) up to DevOps, might be to clone the empty devops repo to a local folder, close VS, manually copy the folder contents from the project into the new local folder created from the clone, then re-open VS and hope that it will sync back to DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

Method to copy local code to Devops:

http://raaviblog.com/how-to-push-project-code-from-local-machine-into-azure-devops-git-repo/

```
1. git init
2. git remote add origin <replace the URL of Azure Git Repo copied earlier>
```

*if you get an error "fatal: remote origin already exists" - you can run:
git remote set-url origin 
.…then continue to step 3. This alternative command replaces Step 2.

```
3. git add .
4. git commit -m “New project added”
5. git push -u origin master
```